# Why ‘on_<propname>’ in kivy is not called?

Tags: properties, kivy

in the kivy document (1.9.0-dev), it says

> Observe using ‘`on_<propname>`’ If you created the class yourself, you
>   can use the ‘`on_<propname>`’ callback:

```
class MyClass(EventDispatcher):
   a = NumericProperty(1) 

   def on_a(self, instance, value): 
      print(’My property a changed to’, value)
```

My code is

```
class MyClass(EventDispatcher):
    a = StringProperty('')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  

    ...

        self.bind(a=self.on_a)    <--- if I remove this

    def on_a(self, instance, value): 
      print(’My property a changed to’, value)
```

This works. But if I remove self.bind(a=self.on_a)

Then on_a function is not called. I thought if I put on_ as a function name then I do not need to do bind(). Do I miss something?

=================================================

Ps. I simplified my code below. It is a full run-able code.

course_view.py:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.adapters.dictadapter import DictAdapter
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class ChangeTest(App):
    pass

class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass

    def load_view(self):
       self.course_view_object = CourseCnDetailListView(view_box = self.ids.view_box) 
       self.clear_widgets()
       self.add_widget(self.course_view_object.master_item_list)


class CourseCnDetailListView(EventDispatcher):
    course_code = StringProperty('course_code_str')    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):        

        self.view_box = kwargs.get('view_box', None)  
        self.course_data= {"1": {"course_code": "it123"},
                            "2": {"course_code": "it456"}
                           }
        list_item_args_converter = \
                lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec["course_code"],
                                        'size_hint_y': None,
                                        'height': 25}

        dict_adapter = DictAdapter(sorted_keys=sorted(self.course_data.keys()),
                                   data=self.course_data,
                                   args_converter=list_item_args_converter,
                                   selection_mode='single',
                                   allow_empty_selection=False,
                                   cls=ListItemButton)
        self.master_item_list = ListView(adapter=dict_adapter,
                                    size_hint=(.3, 1.0))
        dict_adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.course_changed)
        #self.bind(course_code=self.on_course_code)  <-- un-comment this will work
    def on_course_code(self, instance, value):
        print "on_course_code: update string value:", value  
    def redraw(self, *args):
        pass
    def course_changed(self, list_adapter, *args):        

            if len(list_adapter.selection) != 0:
                selection = list_adapter.selection[0] 
                if type(selection) is str:
                    self.course_code = selection
                else:
                    self.course_code = selection.text 

                self.redraw()


ChangeTest().run()            
Factory.register('StartScreen', cls=StartScreen)
```

ChangeTest.kv

```
#: kivy 1.9
#: import ScreenManager kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#: import Screen kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager



ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    StartScreen:
        id: start_screen
        name: 'StartScreen'
        manager: screen_manager


<StartScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: view_box
        Button:
            text: "load view"
            on_release: root.load_view()
```

Comment: Can you post a full runnable example?

Comment: I added the full runable example. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you don't call `super.__init__` in `CourseCnDetailListView`'s `__init__`. Does this work if you do?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you zeeMonkeez.

Yes. That is exactly the problem. After I add the constructor `super(CourseCnDetailListView, self).__init__(**kwargs)`. It works perfectly.

It was accidentally removed when I changed the structure. Thank you very much.

Also it is good to know that it is the default constructor of EventDispatcher make `<on_propname>` work.