# Kivy widget to show updated values of an ObjectProperty's attributes

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, object-property

So I'm trying to make my widgets update whenever the attributes of player change. player is a Player object. The (much) shortened version is below:

```
class Stats(Object):
    def __init__(self, health, max_health):
        self.health=health
        self.max_health=max_health
class Player(Object):
    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats=stats

player= Player(Stats(50,100))
```

My kivy root class is a BoxLayout that has a ProgressBar that shows the health of the player.

```
class GameRoot(BoxLayout):
    p= ObjectProperty(player)
    def do_something(self):
        self.p.stats.health-=5
```

do_something is called every time the enter key is pressed (I've checked that this works). Here is the .kv file for GameRoot

```
GameRoot:
    ProgressBar:
        min:0
        max:root.p.stats.max_health
        value:root.p.stats.health
```

Everything works properly except the widgets won't update when the player's health (or any other attribute) is altered.

The following change to GameRoot made it update:

```
class GameRoot(BoxLayout):
    phealth= ObjectProperty(player.stats.health)
    p= ObjectProperty(player)
    def do_something(self):
        self.phealth-=5
GameRoot:
    ProgressBar:
        min:0
        max:root.p.stats.max_health
        value:root.phealth
```

But this isn't really a good option since Player and Stats both have many instance variables that I need to update whenever they change.

I would appreciate any help. I've looked around but haven't found any solutions.

**Edit**:

When I change everything to properties, I get errors when I try to use the properties in my functions.

```
class Stats(EventDispatcher):
    levels = ListProperty(levels)
    health = NumericProperty()
    xp = NumericProperty()
    level = NumericProperty()
    max_health = NumericProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(Stats, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def set_level(self):
        for l in range(100):
            if self.xp < self.levels[l]:
                self.level= l-1
                break
s= Stats
s.health=10
s.xp=500
s.set_level()
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: set_level() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

In other areas of the code, I get errors that say I can't use NumericProperties as ints or that ListProperties aren't subscriptible.

I apologize if I'm missing something obvious. I only recently started using Kivy.

Comment: You'll want to make `Player` and `Stats` inherit from `EventDispatcher`, and make `health` and `stats` a `Property`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237879/why-on-propname-in-kivy-is-not-called) is question with a common pitfall and some example code.

Comment: It looks like `Stats` is not instantiated in that last example

Comment: I have no clue how to instantiate it. s=Stats() just gives me the TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 0 positional arguments (2 given).  Sorry again- I find KIvy rather confusing.

Comment: Well, your `__init__` is off, too. And that's plain Python :) try `super().__init__(**kwargs)`. But you don't need it if it doesn't do anything

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea why I wrote two __init__s. I didn't even notice I had, haha. It works perfectly now. Thanks again.